# Debug fortran code by visualising execution [Ubuntu18.04]

Tags: debugging, fortran, ide, gfortran

I want to see the step by step execution of a fortran code. 
I have the option of gdb but i want something more visual inside an editor, something like visual studio code, but faster so that I can execute it till a break point and then see the execution from that point onwards step-by-step.

Any recommendation apart from the traditional terminal gdb for the same purpose ?

Comment: Try ddd - should be available in all versions of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) for fortran, based on [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/). It is called [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/) and provides a graphical interface for gdb, in addition to other useful features like makefile support and generation and declaration lookup.